# Scala: scope of objects

Tags: scala, object, scope, apache-spark

I am running a spark application written in Scala 2.9.3. Below is the function `network` which creates a tree of nodes. Each node has a set of unique neighbors which are the child nodes for that particular node. The problem that I am facing is the object `current` is different object (evident by its different address) inside the `for` loop. How can I prevent this and have the `for` loop execute on the same object I declared outside?

```
    def network (root: Node) : Tree =
    {
        var tree = new Tree(root)
        var queue = ListBuffer[Node](root)

        while (!queue.isEmpty &&  queue(0).level<maxlen)
        {
            var current: Node = queue.remove(0)
            println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current1: "+current)
            var neigh = findNeighbor(current.userID)
            for (n <- neigh)
            {
                    if(tree.search(n._1) == null)
                    {
                            var c = new Node(n._1, current.level+1, n._2, n._3)
                            current.addChild(c)
                            println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current2: "+current)
                    }
            }
            println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current3: "+current)
            queue ++= current.neighbors
        }
        return tree
    }
```

Below is the output of the code. Check for values of `current` in 3 places represented by Current1, Current2 and Current3. We observe that Current1 == Current3

```
[vijaygkd@is-joshbloom-hadoop network]$ sbt run
Loading /usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Set current project to Network (in build file:/usr/local/spark/test/vijay/network/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /usr/local/spark/test/vijay/network/target/scala-2.9.3/classes...
[info] Running Network 
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current1: Node@76ab909a
13/10/13 14:23:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/10/13 14:23:50 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/10/13 14:23:50 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current2: Node@4f9e2851
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current2: Node@4f9e2851
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current2: Node@4f9e2851
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current2: Node@4f9e2851
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Current3: Node@76ab909a
[success] Total time: 11 s, completed Oct 13, 2013 2:23:51 PM
```

Additional Info: `findNeighbor` return a RDD containing the tuples of neighbors for node `userID`.
`tree.search` function checks the tree to find if `n` is already present in the tree. Node is only added as a child if it is not present in the tree.
All the functions are working as expect.

Comment: I think this is a function of the various optimizations Scala implements internally to support lazy evaluation, etc. on the JVM. Also, this could be a fine learning exercise, but I think creating this tree defeats the purpose of the optimizations Spark has within the RDD abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be multiple issues with your code. Are you reassigning `current` somewhere? Then perhaps it should be a `val`? Also, why are you assuming the `toString` implementation for `Node` prints our the object's "address"? Is it just printing its `hashCode` maybe? In that case, maybe its `hashCode` changes due to its internal fields changing. Also, you may want to review this page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Answer (score 0):

The underlying Spark framework seems to manipulating the objects in someway. It has to do when I access the RDD `neigh` in the for loop. Converting the RDD to list (since the number of objects is small) solved the problem.